# Qual o nome da menu bar que o youtube, whatapp e outros aplicativos usam?

Tags: android

É um menu onde as opções aparecem no lado esquerdo, igual nesta imagem:
Eu gostaria apenas de saber o nome do menu para implementar. Agradeço desde já.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e esta:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: [Drawer navigation](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

Comment: Caso queira também aprender a fazer um proprio: http://www.rafaeltoledo.net/criando-um-navigation-drawer-customizado-no-android/

Comment: esse mesmo vlw! coloca na resposta que eu te seleciono como resposta correta.

Answer (score 3):

Para começar, sugiro que leia a [documentação](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) oficial do android de como funciona a implementação.

Caso procure uma implementação rápida e fácil, sugiro utilizar a biblioteca **Material Drawer** contida neste [link](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer). Basta adicionar no seu `build.gradle` a dependência:

`compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.0.9@aar') {
    transitive = true
}`

Para utilizar adicione na sua **Activity**:

```
new DrawerBuilder().withActivity(this).build();
```

Desta forma você não precisa criar o layout do menu e itens manualmente, a biblioteca faz isso para você automaticamente. No link da biblioteca contém as instruções de como usar, mas como apontei no começo da resposta, sugiro visitar a documentação oficial para você aprender como o menu é feito.

Answer (score 0):

essa barra de chama Navigation Drawer